# Problem with adding and reaching elements to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on 2D graphical optimal fitting project. I was coding in C++ and changed to Java, therefore I know the algorithm works. But I am having a problem with reaching elements of ArrayList outside of the scope of loop or more likely adding to an ArrayList.

I can reach to an element I want in this scope, but outside of this scope some elements are lost. I know this is irrelevant and probably something   occurs beyond my attention.

Triangle Class:

```
public class Triangle implements Shape, Cloneable
{
 private double length; // size of equaliteral triangle's each edge. 
 private double x,y;
 private boolean rotate; // Flag for rotate by 90 degress around pos(x,y)
 private boolean fill; // Flag for fill 
 private static double total_area = 0;
 private static double total_perim = 0;
 private int[] xPoints;
 private int[] yPoints;
 .
 ...
 }
```

Definitions:

```
 Triangle t2 = (Triangle)small;
 Triangle t = (Triangle)t2.clone();
 List<Shape> shape = new ArrayList<Shape>();
```

In the code below, I draw it as soon as I added it into the List. Method draw() does not matter in this case, it only uses fields such as x and y.

Code 1:

```
// (a,width-a*sqrt(3)) init for fill inside without rotating  
    for(y = r1.getHeight()-tri_height;y>=0;y-=tri_height)
    {
        x=t.getLength()/2.0;
        while(x+t.getLength()/2.0<=r1.getWidth())
        {
            t.setPosition(x+_x,y+_y);
            shape.add((Triangle)t.clone());
            shape.get(size).draw(g); // check this line.
            ++size;
            x+=t.getLength();
        }
    }
```

In this same piece of code, I only draw/print them after insertion is done.

Code 2:

```
// (a,width-a*sqrt(3)) init for fill inside without rotating  
    for(y = r1.getHeight()-tri_height;y>=0;y-=tri_height)
    {
        x=t.getLength()/2.0;
        while(x+t.getLength()/2.0<=r1.getWidth())
        {
            t.setPosition(x+_x,y+_y);
            shape.add((Triangle)t.clone());
            x+=t.getLength();
        }

    }

    for(Shape s:shape)
        s.draw(g);
```

clone() method:

```
@Override
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
{
    return super.clone();
}
```

[Output 1(Wrong)](https://ibb.co/Cbn1rxT)

[Output 2(Expected)](https://ibb.co/vj9v11m)

I am only using draw() method to show the difference better. The problem is the elements are gone after the scope. Or I didn't achieve to add them properly. It shows me that last element I added instead of every element I appended. What am I missing in this case?

Comment: Can you show `Triangle.clone()` method?

Comment: Show us the code for `t`, the thing you clone and add to the list of shapes.  Where do you assign `t`?

Comment: `Triangle.clone()` is useles in this implemention. Could you provide `Triangle` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your problem is in `Triangle.clone()` method. You have references in `Triangle`, like `int[] xPoints` or `int[] yPoints`.

Defualt implementation of `Object.clone()` works only for simple types, but not for references.

```
Triangle t = (Triangle)t2.clone();
t.xPoints == t2.xPoints;  // this is same array (not a copy)
```

All your rectangles are **drawn on the same place**.

#### How to solve

Do not use `clone()` method. In general it is outdated. You have to create like `C++ copy constructor` and manually create copy of your object.

```
public class Triangle implements Shape {
    private static double total_area = 0;
    private static double total_perim = 0;

    private double length;
    private double x,y;
    private boolean rotate;
    private boolean fill;

    private int[] xPoints;
    private int[] yPoints;

    public Triangle(Triangle triangle) {
        this.length = triangle.length;
        this.x = triangle.x;
        this.y = triangle.y;
        this.rotate = triangle.rotate;
        this.fill = triangle.fill;

        this.xPoints = xPoints != null ? Arrays.copyOf(xPoints, xPoints.length) : null;
        this.yPoints = yPoints != null ? Arrays.copyOf(yPoints, yPoints.length) : null;
    }
 }
```

**P.S.**

`int[] xPoints`: `xPoints` - is not an array, this is reference to the array of `int`.

`int[] xPointsCopy = xPoints`: `xPointsCopy` - this is another reference to the **same** array of `int`.